# JavaFx : VBox still occupies space when invisible

Tags: java, javafx

I have a button, on click of which, few controls are supposed to go invisible and also not occupy the space for it. for example, I have a VBox, which I want to make invisible on click of a button, and also to vacate the space that it was occupying when it was visible. I have managed to make it invisible using `vboxQuestionsList.setVisible(false);`. Some solutions suggested using manageProperty, but couldn't understand how to best use it. 
Note : The main parent layout should also collapse and take over the empty space, as soon as the VBox is made "invisible". The VBox is contained inside a row of a GridPane. I need to make the row of the gridpane collapse and remove the space occupied by the VBox.

Comment: "_Some solutions suggested using manageProperty, but couldn't understand how to best use it_" – Have you tried binding it to the visible property so that when one is false so is the other?

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: Managed property "tells" layout whether it should take the control into account when its placing controls. So if your control is invisible but it is still managed layout will still reserve space for it - of course it will jus tbe a blank space with the size of the control. Now if you set both of visible and managed to false control will be invisible and it wont take up space in the layout.